# Liferay session expire even when user is doing activities on the page

Tags: java, ajax, liferay, liferay-6

I have a portlet on my page, for all the user action we are calling the resource URLs with ajax, and only the contents inside the portlet keeps changing.
Now the problem is, even though the user continuously active on the page, we are getting session expired on page. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is because you're not actually navigating around Liferay. Using AJAX doesn't count as the user performing actions that stop their session expiring. You'll need the page to reload or extend the session time.

Comment: IMHO any request that goes to the server should be good to retain the session. The server knows only about requests & responses, the browser is the one that differentiates between an ajax-request and a regular-request that refreshes the page. I may be incorrect, but if you can back-up your answer with some good reference than that can settle the case.

Comment: Well I've had they exact same problem as the question stated and we narrowed it down to the page using purely AJAX. However if you have different answer I would certainly be interested in knowing what you think.

Comment: I tested it and you are correct. So it seems that ajax requests are not considered as part of User activities in Liferay. The reason this may be the case because if the User keeps multiple tabs open and there are portlets (like say chat-portlet) which continuously ping the server without any user action then also the session would be open unnecessarily and would use server resource. But I feel there must be some nice way to get around this rather than manually extending session on every ajax request.

Comment: Ah yes that would make sense, so essentially the chat portlet would artificially extend the session without user intervention. I agree because it's becoming a more of a common problem with AJAX heavy pages. Maybe a session variable / flag?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by following this two steps:

1- add this lines to the **portal-ext.properties** file:

(3000 is the number of minutes before the session will expired)

```
session.timeout=3000

session.timeout.warning=0
```

2-Go to **/conf/web.xml** ( Tomcat server) and edit the session configuration Timeout:

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>3000</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

Comment: Why is necesary add it in two place?

Comment: The tomcat property is to set a range to session timeout, the Liferay property is to set the session Timeout. Tomcat timeout > liferay timeout property

Answer (score 0):

Another way

If You have React/Angular/Vue (SPA) portlets or any JS Code where you can predict that the user will not reload for some time, You can use Liferay web API to extend the session whenever you want.

```
Liferay.Session.extend();
```

You can run the above code in many scenarios, Like calling Ajax Or in some functions where the user is interacting with only SPA apps. Or you can make a global timer in your portlet which extends Liferay's session automatically.